# Wireless range/access issue in old european concrete building

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

My wifes family owns a hotel in Italy which they built in the 1950's.  The structure is 3 story concrete and a boatload of rebar, maybe even some leftover lead paint. A few years back they wanted to semi join the rest of the world and asked me to install a wifi system for the customers.  I went with a:

- 1x - Raytalk RA-595 ticketed system (in which its only for access control, we do not charge anyone)
- 5x - Raytalk RA-100 AP
- 3x - D-Link DWL-3200AP

For the most part, you can receive in the majority of the building.  However, in some rooms you can't.  And what bothers me the most, is 2 of those, the AP is right outisde the door. In those rooms, if you are standing in direct sight of the doorway, you can receive the signals.  However, if you go to the area where the desk and bed is, 3 feet away, the signal drops or disappears. The difference in that area is an internal wall of the restroom.

As it is now, all are set to autochannel.  All AP's are 802.11bg. Interference does not seem to be an issue. My fear is that I will have to install more AP's maybe on the outside of the structure to aim in, in order to capture those dead zones.

Is there anything else to do? Something with stronger radio transmissions? I have read on this site that the 5ghz is not good for my structure so I am at a loss for now.